# What are the names used to describe the "top" and "bottom" portions of a C-style function definition?

Tags: c, function, naming-conventions

I am looking for a name or phrase to identify two distinct parts of a function definition

`1.` The part that looks exactly the same as the function declaration (minus the semi-colon)
`2.` The rest (the portion within and including the curly-braces)

```
int someFunction(int value, bool flag)  // part one
{ ... }                                 // part two
```

Is there an accepted way to describe these two parts?

Comment: At least everyone agrees on the "body" portion! `:)`

Comment: "body" is definitely the accepted answer for part 2. I have chosen "signature" for part one, but the other suggestions ("declarator", "header" and "prototype") are all decent options. Thank you to everyone who chimed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main` has no prototype -- so says the Standard -- and I kinda dislike header.

So I call them 'function signature' and 'function body'.

Answer (score 3):

I call them the function header and function body.  A quick glance at Harbison & Steele comes up with no real names for them.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use prototype and body. Body is use widely for that purpose, prototype has formally a slightly different meaning.

Edit: The standard use *function declarator* (sometimes abbreviated to *declarator*) and *body*.  For instance in 6.9.1/13 which is an example stating

> In the following:

```
extern int max(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

> `extern` is the storage-class specifier and `int` is the type specifier; `max(int a, int b)` is the function declarator; and `{ return a > b ? a : b; }` is the function body.

Comment: Appearing in the standard makes it pretty definitive. I would prefer a term that *includes* the storage-class and type specifiers, but that's just me being picky. Either way, good find!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an interesting tidbit on it... 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3sez2yb.aspx

part one can be the function prototype,
part two is called the function body.

Answer (score 1):

Functions have the function prototype declaration, definition, and body.

```
void SomeFunction(void);  //Prototype declaration.
```

`void SomeFunction(void)  /*Function Definition*/
{
/*Function Body*/
}`

Comment: I have always understood the term "function definition" to include the body. I could (of course) be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the grammar for a function definition:

```
function-definition:
    declaration-specifiers declarator declaration-listopt compound-statement
```

Normally I don't really distinguish between the two.  If pressed, I'd use "body" for the `{...}` portion, and either "signature" or "prototype" for the rest.